# ssrs 2005 page break issue

Tags: reportingservices-2005, page-break

am working on 2005 reporting server and am facing an issue in page break.
my scenario is 
i have 5 data tables say

```
tab1
tab2
tab3
tab4
tab5
```

and user can choose to publish any of the above tables(i have 5 parameter to support the above)

my requirment is if user select to display say tab2 tab4 
in my report i need to have 2 sheets one for tab2 and other for tab4

if user select to display say tab1 tab2 and tab5
in my report i need to have 3 sheets one for tab1 next for tab2 and other for tab5

in 2008 am able to achieve this by the page break setting 
where as in 2005 same settings doesnt work.

i tried the below setting

for each table the visibility expression is:

`IIF(parametername = true , false , true)`

and choosing setting... page break after table and page break before table but i was not able to get the required output

i saw a solution saying rectangle inside a rectangle and i tried the same
i moved my table to the inner rectangle and
the outer rectangle has visibility expression the inner recatngle has the page break option(page break after rectangle/before rectangle/tried with both as well)

it works only for one control say table one 
in my case i have 5 table and i did this solution for all 5 tables with 2 rectangle each for a table but error still persist

any work around for the above?? will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get round this with a horrible solution (but it works).

I placed a small transparent triangle just after each table (they have to be visible as well for the page break to work, so they would need to share the same visibility logic as your tables).

Set Page break *before* the rectangle. This seemed to work for me, the only difference is I am not conditionally controlling the visibility of the tables. The principle should apply though.

I had the same bug as you with page break after table, very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

right click table, and select properties, Check "insert a Page break before this table" under :Page Breaks" title